# Should this question (which has been asked and answered elsewhere) be closed?

Tags: discussion, question-closure

The EL&U question ["Asking questions"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103809/asking-questions) has been asked and answered on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/turn-notify-the-persons-before-30-days-into-a-question). It is very basic, so I don't think it belongs here, but it is not general reference.

Should we close it? If so, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the General Reference reason:

> it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

In this case, that "standard internet reference designed specifically" is ELL.

Or: migrate the question to ELL and then merge the duplicates.

Comment: Can we really call ELL a *standard* Internet reference? It's only been around for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Hmm... when does it become standard? One answer is that if *we* don't start thinking of it as standard, who will? Anyway, that leaves the second option, which is what would normally be done with cross-posted duplicates.

Comment: StackExchange certainly might become a standard Internet reference source. I'm not sure it's yet earned the same cachet as Wikipedia, though. The SE editorial job is made much more difficult than at Wikipedia because at SE there's a new article written every few ... seconds. But if you determine that SE is a standard source then there's really no question about ELL.SE, is there.

Comment: Meta, yes I don't deny that there are problems to define if ELL is a new standard, but I would argue that outiside UK or US we try to uphold the highest standards on StackExchange.